# Is there a name for a problem where you can convert currencies into other currencies to reach a reward?

Tags: algorithm

I have an interesting problem where I have various currencies that can be converted into other currencies and items take a combination of those currencies to buy. For example, given currencies A, B, C, let's say you have A,A and you are able to convert the currencies as follows:

one A to BB (2 Bs)
one B to CC (2 Cs)
one C to AA (3 As)

An item we want to purchase requires AABBCC, given our original input of A,A and a list of exchanges, does there exist a path from A,A to A,A,B,B,C,C? What is the most efficient exchange path to get there?

I'd like to know if there's a name to this kind of problem so I can look up algorithms on how to optimize this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'Arbitrage' is the word for one or more trades that exploit exchange rates in order to profit. In the real world, currency arbitrage is constantly being exploited for minute profits, and this exploitation keeps the currency exchange rates consistent.

You could run BFS from (2,0,0) where the tuple represents (As,Bs,Cs). Neighboring tuples as per your exchange rates, so the two arcs out of (2,0,0) go to (1,2,0) and (0,0,1). The latter of those is a dead end, but from (1,2,0) you can go on to (0,4,0) and (1,1,2). Keep going until you reach something that dominates (2,2,2). BFS guarantees that this will be the shortest path.

```
BFS results starting at 200 (imagine these are tuples so 200 = (2,0,0)
step 0: 200
step 1: 120, 001
step 2: 040, 112
step 3: 032, 104, 311
step 4: 024, 231, 303, 510
step 5: 016, 223, 151, 430, 502
```

We stop on the fifth step because 223 dominates 222. We can then trace our path backwards: 223 <- 024 <- 032 <- 040 <- 120 <- 200